# The shapes of the array expressions do not conform

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm  trying write a code and define a function which I need to to run MRQMIN subroutine

```
  program  mrqmin
  !ifort mrqmin.f90 module_cosmo.o gaussj.o covsrt.o nrtype.o nrutil.o nr.o -o mrqmin
  implicit none
  integer i,b,ok
  double precision,dimension(:),allocatable :: a,Nrow,iz,Nbin,fi,fiStdDev,fiAvr,Magbin,zup
  double precision,dimension(:),allocatable :: fiStdDev2,RfiStdDev2,fi_expected,DFI,CHISQ
  double precision fi_star,alpha,M_star
  open(1,file='new.asc')
  b=14
  ! Ln10=2.3025
   A=0.4*2.3025
        do I=1,b        

                read (1,*) Nrow(I),iz(I),Nbin(I),fi(I),fiStdDev(I),fiAvr(I),Magbin(I),zup(I)

                  fiStdDev2(I)=fiStdDev(I)*fiStdDev(I)
                  RfiStdDev2(I)=1/fiStdDev2(I)
            write(*,*)fiStdDev2(I),RfiStdDev2(I)
                  fi_expected(I)=A*fi_star*10**(0.4*(alpha+1)*(M_star-Magbin(I)))*exp(-10**(0.4*(M_star-Magbin(I))))
                  DFI(I)=fi_expected(I)-FI(I)
                  CHISQ(I)=DFI(I)*DFI(I)*RfiStdDev2(I)
            end do
  deallocate(a,Nrow,iz,Nbin,fi,fiStdDev,fiAvr,Magbin,zup,fiStdDev2,RfiStdDev2,fi_expected,CHISQ,DFI)

  end program mrqmin
```

but I'm receving the error :  The shapes of the array expressions do not conform.   [FI_EXPECTED]

in case I have used this function with the same shape in an other code but I didn't had problem, I can understand where is my mistake?

Comment: Make at least a minimal effort to make your code comprehensible.  Eliminate the commented-out lines, rationalise the indentation, cut out unnecessary white space.  Why should I work hard to understand your code ?  And did your compiler or run-time system tell you the line in which the error occurred ?  If it did, tell us too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you *exactly* where the problem is: in the line where `fi_expected` is being defined:

```
fi_expected(I)=A*fi_star*10**(0.4*(alpha+1)*(M_star-Magbin(I)))&
                     *exp(-10**(0.4*(M_star-Magbin(I))))
```

Note that `fi_expected` has dimension `b` while `A` has dimension `3`. This is because Fortran is **not** case sensitive, so `a` and `A` are the same thing, so you need to differentiate `a` from `A` in whatever way you feel best.

Note also that you are defining `A` *before* allocating it, which will cause a run-time error.